# ASP MVC Areas and JSON POST

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

I have a project with areas and would like to post a view model as JSON to a controller method.

This is what I have, with performance being generated in the default area and passed to the view in area `SeatSelection`:

```
$("#addToCartButton").click(function () {
    var json = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(performance));
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://@(Request.Url.Host)/SeatSelection/Home/AddToCart',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: json,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

And the action method for testing:

```
[System.Web.Http.Route("SeatSelection_AddToCart")]        
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public JsonResult AddToCart(PerformanceViewModel performance)
{
    return Json(performance.Name);
}
```

I created the following route:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "SeatSelection_AddToCart",
    "SeatSelection/Home/AddToCart",
    new { action = "AddToCart", controller = "Home", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new string[] { "myProject.Areas.SeatSelection.Controllers" }
);
```

But all I get is a internal server error 500. I also tried to use `[FromBody]` and setting a breakpoint to the method, but it is not invoked. I can't figure out what's wrong or missing, please help.

UPDATE
This is the json / performance:

```
PerformanceID=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&Name=Performance+15&StartDate=%2FDate(1360364400000)%2F&EndDate=%2FDate(1500328800000)%2F&LatestDateBookable=%2FDate(1450911600000)%2F&Organizer=Organizer+15&Location=Location+15&Availability=75&IsFull=false&IsBookable=true&HasPrice=true&BookableSeats=11&BookedSeats=94&Description=Description+of+Performance+15&Price=443
```

I found an error: "invalid json primitive: performanceid"

Comment: I'd guess that `return Json(performance.Name);` generates a null reference exception (and returns a 500 internal server error) as `performance` is probably null. Could you add an example of the JSON that is sent to the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I would recommend you to use `@Url.Action` helper method instead of generating url like this: `https://@(Request.Url.Host)/SeatSelection/Home/AddToCart`.

Secondly, always validate params which comes from the browser. `return Json(performance.Name)` looks suspicious. What is `performance` will be null? This might be a problem of your internal server error 500.

If this is not a problem then try to send string instead of JSON to the server and validate and parse JSON on the server side.

Comment: Yep, I often had such issues in the past. Sending string helped in most of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Url.Action method like this. I suppose `SeatSelection` is an area in your project.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("AddToCart", "Home", new { Area = "SeatSelection"})',
```